# How to tell if Celery is using librabbitmq?

Tags: celery, librabbitmq

According to [Celery Documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#librabbitmq):

> ### librabbitmq
>
> If you’re using RabbitMQ (AMQP) as the broker then you can install the librabbitmq module to use an optimized client written in C:
>
> ```
> $ pip install librabbitmq
> ```
>
> The ‘amqp’ transport will automatically use the librabbitmq module if it’s installed, or you can also specify the transport you want directly by using the pyamqp:// or librabbitmq:// prefixes.

I installed `librabbitmq` and changed the `BROKER_URL` setting so that it starts with `librabbitmq://`.

How do I verify that Celery is now using librabbitmq (i.e., that I did everything correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall librabbitmq.
2. Ensure that `BROKER_URL` starts with `librabbitmq://`.
3. Try to do something with celery (e.g., `python manage.py celery worker` if using [djcelery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)).
4. **The command will fail with `ImportError: No module named librabbitmq`.**
5. Reinstall librabbitmq.
6. Repeat step 3.
7. **The command should now work without any problems.**

It's not 100% conclusive, but does yield a reasonably good indication that celery is using librabbitmq.